# Difference between training and testing phase in caffe

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

this might seem like a silly question, but I am trying to understand to what extent the testing phase in caffe is important for good results.  Of course the training phase is important, but is the testing phase simply to test out how much loss is obtained periodically on a set that is not trained? If this is the case, does the size of my test set really matter? Does testing even matter at all?  I ask because I currently have some serious overfit problems.  If I have a large dataset (>50 000 images), how should I go about splitting them between test and train?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caffe never use the result of the test sets while doing training and modify some parameter to fix some issues like overfitting.

The usage of a validation set (test set during training) is for us to visualize whether the model overfits the data by looking at the accuracy or loss values, by plotting them or looking at the outputs.

For example, if the loss of the training set keeps reducing at every iterations and the loss of the test set keeps increasing, this is a solid case of the model overfitting the training set. For getting such conclusions, the images selected for the test set shouldn't be the same as that of the training set. Its ideal to keep a 1:10 ratio for test-train image count. If the test set was using a subset of the trainset, the loss of the testset would have decreased and we may not detect the overfitting behaviour of the model.